# Question regarding the image of the homomorphism in the 2nd isomorphism theorem

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

Let $G$ be a group, $H$ a subgroup, $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$. Let $f$ be the map $$f: H \rightarrow G/N, \: h \mapsto hN$$ I am trying to find the image of this homomorphism:

$Im(f) = \{hN  \: | h \in H\} = H/N.\:$     However, in my textbook the image is written as $HN/N. \:$ I understood the two are equivalent since $$HN/N =  \{hnN  \: | h \in H, n \in N\} = \{hN  \: | h \in H, n \in N\} = \{hN  \: | h \in H\} = H/N$$

but I'm wondering why $HN/N$ is written instead of $H/N$.

Comment: First of all, the notation is “$G/N$” not “$N\backslash G$”.

Comment: @k.stm Yeah sorry, I keep confusing the notation because I rarely use forward slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s view this from a mere set-theoretic level first. Stricty speaking, one only defines for a group $G$ and a subgroup $N ⊆ G$
$$G/N = \{gN;~g ∈ G\}.$$
Of course, it would be also okay to further define for subgroups $H ⊆ G$
$$H/N = \{hN;~h ∈ H\}.$$
This seems analogous. However, this kind of subverts the two real-life interpretations of the notation “$G/N$”.

1. *Group actions*. More generally, if a group $N$ is acting on a set $X$ *from the right*, then the orbit space of this action is denoted by
   $$X/N = \{xN;~x ∈ X\}.$$
   (For a left action of $N$ on $X$, thee orbit space is $N\backslash X = \{Nx;~x ∈ X\}$.)
2. *Factor groups*. To denote the factor group of a group $G$ by a *normal* subgroup $N$, we write
   $$G/N = \{[g]_N;~g ∈ N\}$$
   and mean by it a set endowed with a group structure.

For 1.), we need $N$ to act on $H$ from the right, but the right action from $N$ on $G$ doesn’t necessarily restrict to $H$. There might be $h ∈ H$ and $n ∈ N$ with $hn \notin H$. In fact, when $N \not ⊆ H$, there is some $n ∈ N$ with $n \notin H$, so for $h = 1$, $hn \notin H$. Hence, we need $H ⊆ N$ here.

For 2), we need $N$ to be a subgroup of $H$ by definition. So again we need $H ⊆ N$ here.

Hence, $H/N$ neither is an orbit space nor a factor group in general, but only if $H ⊆ N$.

Also note that the orbit space $G/N$ of the right action of $N$ on $G$ gives an implementation of the factor group $G/N$, which is why we use the same notation for both concepts. They fit together seamlessly.

So, all in all, the notation only makes sense in general when $H ⊆ N$, which is why one chooses to enlarge the group $H$ to $HN$ (which really is a subgroup since $N$ is normal) and write “$HN/N$” instead of “$H/N$”. As you already checked, this set gives the correct image.

Comment: Thanks. So just to clarify, what you're saying is that for $H/N$ to be a subgroup it's necessary, by definition, that $N \subseteq H$? And hence $H/N$ is generally extended to $HN/N$, although they are equivalent? (P.S. I haven't covered group actions yet.)

Comment: @Hai Well, “for $H/N$ to be a *factor group*” (not *subgroup*), yes. It’s more a matter of adhering to clear and conceptual definitions. Writing “$HN/N$” is the formally correct way to express this factor group, whereas “$H/N$” is, strictly speaking, ill-defined in general. Privately, some or maybe even many people *do* write “$H/N$” because it looks neater, but it’s formally not correct. That is all.

Comment: Yeah I meant to say factor group, sorry. And yes, that's how I was viewing it as well. Thanks for all the help.